# how to make apps on blackberry emulator to connect internet when the PC is behind a proxy server

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

My PC configured behind a proxy server for internet access. I referred to the blackberry simulator related posts and changed my MDS server setting as follows

```
application.handler.http.proxyEnabled = true

application.handler.http.proxyHost=hostname

application.handler.http.proxyPort=hostport

application.handler.http.proxyUser=username

application.handler.http.proxyPass=password
```

After this when MDS is started with simulator, I am able to use the browser. But when I click the browser it asks for the username, password and domain name. After this the internet works properly

Here is the problem. For the same settings when I click the maps app in the blackberry it is not working. Kindly let me know what has to be changed.

Comment: more like http://serverfault.com/ question

Answer (score 3):

Not all apps will use the MDS transport to communicate - for example if the app uses Direct TCP or Wi-Fi, it will bypass your MDS server and go directly over the computer's TCP/IP stack (when running in the simulator).  Unfortunately in this case the simulator doesn't use any system-level proxy settings (i.e. the proxy settings set in IE) -- so it won't know about your proxy server and probably fail.

I've mentioned this deficiency to RIM and I'm hopeful they'll address it in future emulators.  It would make it so much easier to debug with tools such as Charles or Fiddler.

Comment: Marc, are you saying it's not possible to setup a simulator to use my local wireless and proxy at the same time? I've built an app that fires up various emulators (typical platforms; WP7, iPhone, Android & BlackBerry) and uses the FiddlerCore to intercept requests from the emulator's browser so I can tamper with them. I must have the ability to muck with the emulator's proxy details in order to facilitate this functionality.

Comment: Probably not - the simulator doesn't have an option to use a proxy server (unless you're using MDS).  You might be able to use a proxy server that intercepts low-level Windows HTTP/socket APIs - but I have no idea if that's even possible.